# Creating ACL module using NoSQL Database VS. SQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, acl, nosql

I need to write an ACL module for a system I'm working on.
I've written ACLs before - but I always have the feel that it can be more efficient

As I didn't work with NoSQL databases too much, and I'm seriously considering start using them for the purposes where it has its advantages - I would like to hear your opinion whether ACL module would be a good example for such case

The ACL should consist of AROs (Access request objects - such as site members), ACOs (Access Control Objects - such as actions on items in the site. [for example: view product no. 2])

And both should be grouped as a tree - so that I can have groups of members and groups of products.

My recent implementation used a set of defined permissions (each had its own number) that was combined to one number with bitwise OR operations to set the permission level of the ARO

for example: if `view = 1, modify = 2, delete = 4` and user #1 can view and delete object #3 we will have this row in the database (mysql db in my case):

```
|  user_id   |   object_id   |    level   |
===========================================
|     1      |      3        |      5     |
```

In order to get the full hierarchy of permissions for the user I created a recursive join query (while specifying the maximum depth I'm supporting) and then checked for a permission definition on all of the object in the ARO's path to the root of the tree

I've now seen an interesting way to eliminate the need in the joins part in [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Back to my question -

In NoSQL the data is saved as objects which can be in a tree data structure "out of the box" - so it seems more reasonable to have at least the groups hierarchy in such structure

What do you think would be the better solution for the most efficient and generic ACL system?